# MySQL: Select all words in a string with Natural Language Mode/ Match Against

Tags: mysql

There's a record in the details column in my table and it contains '...big data etc...'. However, when I ran the query below, the record with '...big data etc...' is included. Now, my question is, how can I exclude that record with my query 'Big Machine Learning'? I just want to query a records containing 'Big Machine Learning', it's okay to have a details with '...machine big learning...' as long as the whole string has been used in querying not just the word 'Big'.

`SELECT details FROM story MATCH(details) AGAINST('Big Machine Learning' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)`

Comment: Try to use the [boolean mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) (and specifically the + sign), not the natural language mode.

Comment: I tried `AGAINST('+Big +Machine +Learning' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` and it works, however I don't want to strip a string just to add a `+` sign before each word. Is there any other way to query just like that without prefixed plus symbol?

Comment: AHA! This is working, hi5. `AGAINST('"Big Machine Learning"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Comment: If you enclose the phrase in `"`, it will search for the phrase in that order (so `'...machine big learning...'` will not be found). If you are ok with this (your question stated it should be found), `"` works too.